# Rspec: Using factories in other factories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm writing a cost for a create method that will add a comment to a post.

The comment belongs to a user and a post. And a post belongs to a user.

When I run my test I get a validation error saying that the username and email have already been taken. I've tried using build as well as build_stubbed in both my factories and in the test, but neither of them worked. I think it has to do with the fact that I'm using create, but I'm not entirely sure.

Any advice would be much appreciated

Here are my factories:

```
users.rb

FactoryGirl.define do
factory :user do
    username "test_user"
    email "test_user@email.com"
    password "password"
end

factory :user_2, class: User do
    username "test_user_2"
    email "test_user_2@email.com"
    password "password"
end

factory :invalid_user, class: User do
    username ""
    email ""
    password ""
end
end
```

---

```
outlets.rb

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :outlet do
    category "vent"
    title "MyString"
    body "MyText"
    urgency 1
    user factory: :user
  end

  factory :outlet_2, class: Outlet do
    category "rant"
    title "MyString_2"
    body "MyText_2"
    urgency 2
    user factory: :user_2
  end

  factory :invalid_outlet, class: Outlet do
    category "qualm"
    title ""
    body ""
    urgency 3
    user factory: :user
  end
end
```

---

```
comments.rb

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :comment do
    body "This is a comment"
    user factory: :user
    outlet factory: :outlet_2
  end

  factory :invalid_comment, class: Comment do
    body "This is a comment"
    user nil
    outlet nil
  end  
end
```

---

Here is my test:

```
describe 'create' do
        context 'with valid attributes' do

            let(:outlet) { FactoryGirl.create(:outlet) }
            let(:valid_comment_params) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:comment) }

            it "creates a new comment" do
                expect { post :create, params: { id: outlet, :comment => valid_comment_params } }.to change(Comment, :count).by(1)
            end
        end
    end
```

Here are my models:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :outlet

  validates :body, :user, :outlet, presence: true
  validates :body, length: { in: 1..1000 }
end
```

---

```
class Outlet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments

  validates :category, :title, :body, :urgency, :user, presence: true
  validates :title, length: { in: 1..60 }
  validates :body, length: { in: 1..1000 }
  validates :urgency, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 1, less_than_or_equal_to: 10 }
  validates :category, inclusion: { in: ['vent', 'rant', 'qualm'] }
end
```

---

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :outlets
    has_many :comments

    validates :username, :email, :encrypted_password, presence: true
    validates :username, :email, uniqueness: true
    validates :password, length: { in: 5..30 }
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :lockable, :timeoutable 
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable
end
```

Comment: would you mind posting your model code as well (specifically the validations)? That will help guide the answer.

Comment: Okay, I just edited with model code

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here is you keep trying to create a user with the same email and username that you just created another user with.  In order to avoid this in your factories, you should strive to make the values dynamic.  Since the main issues currently are the uniqueness validations, lets start with those.

```
factory :user do
  sequence(:username) { |n| "test_user#{n}" }
  sequence(:email)    { |n| "test_user#{n}@email.com" }
  password "password"
end
```

that way, you can use the same factory to create 2 distinct users

```
user = FactoryGirl.create :user
user_2 = FactoryGirl.create :user
```

Comment: When I try this, I either get "can't find out with id= "  or It was supposed to change count by 1 but it changed by 0

Comment: in your test you want to do `expect { post :create, params: { :comment => valid_comment_params } }.to change(Comment, :count).by(1)`  You don't need an `id` value since you haven't created the object yet (it doesn't have an id until it is persisted)